# Pick the prototype to avoid if-else

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

The below code snippet I found on one blogs to avoid if-else statement. This code is very modular and can be easily extended. But I am not able to get this to work.

```
CatModel.prototype.makeWords = function () {
    console.log('inside catmodel') 
    this.setWord('meow')
    this.sayIt()
}

DogModel.prototype.makeWords = function () {
    console.log('inside dogmodel')
    this.setWord('bark')
    this.saySomething()
}


// somewhere else
var makeWords = function (type) {
    var model = namespace[type + 'Model']
    model.makeWords()
}

makeWords('cat')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the `CatModel` and `DogModel` functions are declared somewhere and `setWord` and `sayIt` are also set up on their `prototype` object.

You'd need to put `CatModel` and `DogModel` in an object and refer to it from `namespace` (which I'd recommend *not* calling `namespace`):

```
var namespace = {
    CatModel: CatModel,
    DogModel: DogModel
};
```

Then when creating an instance, use `new` (you always use `new` with constructor functions). I'd also put the `()` on the call even though strictly speaking they're optional if you don't have parameters to pass:

```
var makeWords = function (type) {
    var model = new namespace[type + 'Model']()
    // ---------^^^--------------------------^^
    model.makeWords()
}
```